# Amazon Simple Email Service: link in mail automatically called?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application with an angular frontend running on AWS. When a new user signs up, he receives a mail with a url containing a confirmation code. When the user clicks on that url, the application marks the mail address of the user as confirmed. This works nicely when I'm running the application on localhost.

When I run the application on AWS, around 10 seconds (!) after the user has signed up, the url in the mail with the confirmation code is automatically called, WITHOUT anyone clicked on that url in the received mail. Any ideas how this can happen? Maybe some kind of mail scanner sitting anywhere and checking links inside sent mails? This sounds very strange to me, but I can't imagine any other reasons?

Comment: Hi, it may be due to your email server security suites that look at tracked links to verify whether a site holds malicious content.
Can you share us the render format of your link please

Comment: The link has the following format: https://[website]/mail-confirmation/[id]/[token] and is sent in a plain-text mail. The receiving mail account is a business account operated by outlook.com / microsoft.

Comment: Can you try to send your body as HTML and encapsulate your link between ```span``` like this ```<span>yourlink</span>```, it can prevent security check from automatically open your link

Comment: You may want to tie confirmation to a session cookie already stored in the browser.  This way a 3rd party clicking the link will not trigger activation.  (don't know why this is happening, btw, but it's a workaround anyway, and does improve the security of your activation link... only that browser's session can activate the account/e-mail)

Comment: @Q.Rey: I've tried it, does not make a difference. Thanks anyway! @ browsermator: I like the direction of thinking, but then a user has no possibility to confirm his mail address when he registered e.g. in the browser's privacy mode.

Comment: I believe session cookies will still work.  Incognito just prevents saving things after the browser closes.

Comment: If the user closes the browser, though, they will not be able to validate... you might inform them of that.  You should also check to be sure that link is actually being hit.  It's also possible there's a bug somewhere... maybe a trigger in the DB that's doing the wrong thing?